# Magento 2.3 transfer from localhost to live server issue

Tags: server-setup, upload, transfer

I have a specific question as a beginner in magento.

1. I built my magento 2.3 in localhost with xampp on windows.
2. I exported my database as a .sql
3. I exported all magento files to the server
4. I changed the core-config_data  URL entries to the server URL`s
5. I entered the server new infos in env.php
6. I imported the database in phpMyadmin

all seems to be well done, but once I try to connect my shop in browser, it still redirect to local url : 127.0.0.1 impossible access error.

So my question is : is there another file to edit in Magento that still redirect to the local 127.0.0.1 URL ?

Thank you so much
yves

Comment: Search for 127.0.01 in your database and if found replace with host

Comment: Thanks Pawan ! I will try this. Do you think the redirect only in database or in magento files too ?

Comment: Sorry but still the same redirect to my local URL

Comment: most chances are in database.did you search in database ?

Comment: Yes, in database I changed all 127.0.0.1 to my server URL. still the same redirect to the local URL. My env.php is correct, and core_config_data base url too.. Obviously, there should be a magento file that create this redirect...

Comment: please run `rm -rf var/* generated/*` `php bin/magento c:f`

Comment: the php bin/magento c:f command gives : <b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '{' in <b>/homepages/46/d204221203/htdocs/shop1/bin/magento</b> on line <b>13</b><br />

Comment: but I don`t see any error on line 13